# Run selenium webdriver IntelliJ/Java/JUnit w/multiple computers on same central project folder

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, maven-3

I would like to have laptops and vm's creating, maintaining and running selenium tests all from the same common IntelliJ Project folder on a network shared drive.

Is it possible to setup a centralized project folder for IntelliJ so that multiple computers with IntelliJ installed running Selenium Webdriver and JUnit can execute the same tests from a singular location even at the same time? I am not using robot.

I am using IntelliJ 2017.2.3, Java 1.8.0_121, JUnit 4.12, Maven 3.3.9

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

My advice here would be to do the following:

- Make sure your project is in a reputable version control system (GitHub/Git)
- Determine your exact requirements of why you need to carry this out?
- Research selenium-grid (you can run tests on multiple browsers/devices at the same time, this way you could run them on one machine pointing to one grid instance, and on the other machine point it to another.
- Look into CI/CD (Jenkins) - This will allow you to parameterize your tests so you can kick them off at specific times pointing to different grid instances.